# Angular4 Injecting Service class - code in constructor not finished when service method called?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, single-page-application, sanity

I'm trying to get into Angular4/5. I have a connection to a CMS service called Sanity (https://www.sanity.io/). The issue I am having is that this service is injected to a ProductsComponent class and I call methods in that service at the component's ngOnInit method. However I am getting the following error when I try to recompile using ng serve command:

```
ERROR in src/app/sanity.service.ts(21,14): error TS2339: Property 'fetch' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

Here is the component where I inject the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Query } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/di';
import { SanityService } from '../sanity.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-product',
    templateUrl: './products.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

    products: object[];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanityService: SanityService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.sanityService.getProducts((res) => {
            this.products = res;
        });

    }

}
```

here is the service code (sanity.service.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//const sanityClient = require('@sanity/client');
import * as SanityClient from '@sanity/client';

@Injectable()
export class SanityService {

    sanityClient: object;

    constructor() {
        this.sanityClient = SanityClient({
            projectId: 'someidhere',
            dataset: 'somedatabase',
            useCdn: true
        });
    }

    getProducts(callback) {
        let query = "*[_type == 'product']{ name, _id, description, price, 'imageUrl': image.asset->url }";
        this.sanityClient
            .fetch(
                query, // Query
                {} // Params (optional)
            ).then(res => {
                //console.log('5 movies: ', res)
                //this.products = res;
                callback(res);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error('Oh no, error occured: ', err)
            });
    }



    getProductById(id, callback) {
        var query = `*[_id == '${id}']{ name, _id, description, price, 'imageUrl': image.asset->url }`;
        this.sanityClient
            .fetch(
                query, // Query
                {} // Params (optional)
            ).then(res => {
                //console.log('PRODUCT: ', res)
                //this.products = res;
                callback(res);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error('Oh no, error occured: ', err)
            });
    }

}
```

My suspicion is that the object being created/set in the service's constructor is yet to finish 'loading' when the 'getProducts()' function is called and thus, the 'fetch' property does not exist error.

I'm really stumped here...can someone help me out?

Also here is my app.component.ts just in case:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SanityService } from './sanity.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [SanityService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private sanityService: SanityService) {}
}
```

Comment: Don't type your variables as 'plain object', because then typescript compiler will treat it as an "empty object" without any property or methods in it... you will get the compile time error when you try to access any property of the object by using dot operator (Object.propertyName), however array notation (Object["propertyName"]) will work fine.

Comment: @NikxFabrizio thanks for the input...however you did not mention what to declare variable as....seems it 'any' will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to type your SanityClient as `any` or, if you have typings included, as `SanityClient`. Typing as an object tells TypeScript to treat it as a plain object without any additional function, therefore this error is emitted!

So changing `sanityClient: object` to `sanityClient: any` should allow your application to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Interface or a class Model which contains `fetch` method.

With interface:

```
export interface Fetch {
    fetch
}
```

Or with model:

```
export class Fetch {
   fetch
}
```

So after creating a class model for example, import it and do this stuff:

```
sanityClient: Fetch;
```

the difference between the two can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces).

> Consider using a class instead of an interface for services and
>   declarables (components, directives, and pipes).
>
> Consider using an interface for data models.

Comment: Why not just declare variable as 'any' like Oclyde correctly suggested above? any reason why you way should be done instead of the simpler "any" declaration? thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you're true, but if you want other type of object.